# SQL, Retrieving from a table

Tags: sql

I am a junor developer, I dont know what logic should I use to overcome thi situation:
Imagine, in a table, we have 5 unique key attributes plus two attributes that include startingdate and Finishingdate. Key1,key2,key3,key4,key5,startingDate, FinishingDate
To retrieve only one record from this table, we have only 4 keys instead of 5, plus a date of a particular day.
While retrieving, we have 4 keys available plus, a condition that,
That particular day must be between the startingdate and the FinishingDate.

You know that we cannot retrieve a 5-key table with 4 keys.  But unfortunately we don't have a way to get the fifth key.
It is important to retrieve only one record from the table.

The solution that came to my mind was to use the startingdate and endingdate attributes, in such a way that those two dates give a unique property to that record when it enters the table, I mean, if we can make a condition for  Make each record of the table so that the time period of each record does not interfere with other records of the table.
In this case, we can treat that time period as a unique key.  In this way, we can retrieve the table with 4 keys and the date of a specific day without the fifth key, with the help of the Where keyword.  But the problem is that, I don't know how, the time period, when entering information into the table, set a condition for the time period so that this attribute is entered into the table in a unique way for each record.  Obviously, record 00000 has a date, and record 00001 can itself have a date conflicting with record 00000.  What method do you use to solve the problem in such situations?

I tried to find a solution and I ended up not knowinf what to do.

Comment: Put some sample data to provide context. Right now with your description there is a confusion between date and "day", so provide data and sample query and result that you expect.

Comment: I.e. provide a [mcve]. Also show us your current attempt.

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms used. (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @PraveenB hey, thanks for replying, I edited the post, more information are added

Comment: Your question describes a 'temporal' table (time-variant); there are ways of representing these, and using StartingDate and FinishingDate makes queries easier but harder to guarantee that the rows for the same partial key don't overlap. One way of achieving that is to use an insert/update trigger to disallow such changes to the table. Other approaches include keeping only the startingDate, and allowing the query to deal with finding where it ends (by finding the subsequent row; can be added to a view). DBMS vendors provide different features to support this; you need to specify.

Comment: The question would be easier to understand with a `create table` statement, some sample data, and your expected results. Also which database are you using?